# Representing a network using a relational schema

Tags: sql, graph, nosql

I want to represent a network using a relational schema.

The entities of my network are:

1. **Node** : a point on the network.
2. **Arc** : a direct connection between 2 nodes
3. **Path** : an ordered sequence of arcs.

Is a relational model suited for representing such a network ?

I am considering SQL/No SQL as the options.
The size of my data is not expected to grow at a very rapid pace. I do not want to pick SQL/No SQL based on any predefined query patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Often the best tool to represent a network is a graph database like Neo4j.

But when you want to do it in SQL, both Node (or `Vertex` in graph theory) and Arc (properly called `Edge`) would get an own table. A `Vertex` would contain only the data about the vertex itself, and no information about its relations to others. An `Edge` would contain the primary keys of the two nodes it links, plus any meta-information about the link itself.

When you need to store paths of multiple nodes, you should use two tables. A `Path` table with the path-id and any data about the path as a whole, and another table `PathVertex` consisting of Path-ID, number in that path and primary key of the `Edge` table which contains all the positions a path consists of.